# Find the probability that at least one of the next 6 customers bought black shoes.

Tags: probability

Suppose that 55% of the clients of a shoe shop buy black shoes. Find the probability that at least one of the next 6 customers bought black shoes. Assume that customers assume independently.

**My work**
Let

$A_1=$"1 customer shop a black shoes"
$A_2=$"2 customer shop a black shoes"
$A_3=$"3 customer shop a black shoes"
$A_4=$"4 customer shop a black shoes"
$A_5=$"5 customer shop a black shoes"
$A_6=$"6 customer shop a black shoes"

Here i'm a little confused, i'm think use this

$P(A1\cap A_2\cap A_3...\cap A_6)=P(A_1)....P(A_6)$ but i think don't have sense the intersection. Can someone help me?

This can be solved used:

*Bayer Form
*Independence
*Total probability
*Conditional probability
*Rule of product

Comment: Try to compute the probability that none of the customers buy black shoes. Then use that $P(A) = 1 - P(A^C)$.

Comment: Just FYI: using your notation, the probability should have been $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_6)$ since you want AT LEAST one of them buying black shoes.  However, writing it this way doesn't help you in this case and you'd still have to use the trick by @ThomasBladt ...  Writing it with intersections $\cap$ you are describing the case that ALL SIX of them buy black shoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $55\%$ of the clients buy black shoes, then we can take it to mean that every time a customer buys a pair of shoes, they have a $\frac{55}{100}$ probability of being black shoes.

Now what is the probability that, out of $6$ customers, none of them buy black shoes? Well, each one has a probability $\frac{45}{100}$ of *not* buying black shoes. Since the customers are assumed to be independent, then we have that the probability that *none* of the $6$ customers buy black shoes is
$\left(\frac{45}{100}\right)^6$ and thus if $A= \{\text{ at least one of the next $6$ customers buys a pair of black shoes} \}$ then

$$P(A)=1-\left(\frac{45}{100}\right)^6 \approx 99.17\%.$$

Comment: Excelent Thomas, thanks for your answer.